# Jquery.post submit form with 2 buttons

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

when i submit my form, only popup box appears without any query results. I have 2 submit buttons which trigger the query of my php script. The query results should be displayed in a popup box. i suppose, something should be wrong with my jquery code. here is my code:

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect" id="modal">
<div class="md-content" id="content">   
<h3>Query Results</h3>
<div id="result"><?php include 'query/_query.php'; ?></div>
<button class="md-close">Close</button>
                </div>      
            </div>
                <div class="column">
                <div align="center">
<form id="query" action="" >
<button class="md-trigger md-setperspective" name="queryM" data-modal="modal" id="queryM">Query Person</button>
<button class="md-trigger md-setperspective" name ="queryG" data-modal="modal" id="queryG">Query Order</button>
</form><br>
</div>
<script> 
// formular query
$( "#query" ).submit(function( event ) {

  // prevent pagerefresh
  event.preventDefault();

  // querym & queryg
  var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( "button[name='queryM']" ).val(),
    term = $form.find( "button[name='queryG']" ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

  // post data
  var posting = $.post( url, { queryM: term, queryG: term  } );

  // results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
</script>   
            </div>
        </div>

<script src="js/loader.js"></script>
<script src="js/modal.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, change your `term` variables to `termM` and `termG` both in the definition and usage respectively:

```
termM = $form.find( "button[name='queryM']" ).val(),
termG = $form.find( "button[name='queryG']" ).val(),
.....
var posting = $.post( url, { queryM: termM, queryG: termG  } );
```

You can't assign two different values to a single variable and expect to retrive them. The first value will be overwritten by the second.

In the `done` call back, you may want to do `console.log( data )` to confirm that you're getting the desired response.

Comment: ok thanks, it works. but i get 2 queries at one time, how can i separate them?

Comment: Two queries? Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: well, i want only one query when i click on the button, but i solved that by creating second form